# How to construct one Byte Array which will have multiples data types values in it?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, bytebuffer

I have one header file `client_address.h` in C++ in which I have below declarations -

```
typedef uint64_t   CustomerAddress;

void client_data(uint8_t datacenter, 
                  uint16_t client_id, 
                  uint8_t data_id, 
                  uint32_t data_counter,
                  CustomerAddress& customer_address);
```

And then in my implementation file `client_address.cpp` I have implementation of `client_data` method - So what it does is it takes couple of variable as the parameters and then make one final variable `customer_address` out of it which is `uint64_t`

```
void client_data(uint8_t datacenter, 
                  uint16_t client_id, 
                  uint8_t data_id, 
                  uint32_t data_counter,
                  CustomerAddress& customer_address)
{
    customer_address = (uint64_t(datacenter) << 56)
                    + (uint64_t(client_id) << 40)
                    + (uint64_t(data_id) << 32)
                    + data_counter;
}
```

I need to do the same thing in Java by which I will have one variable which will be `customer_address` and it will be uint64_t in Java (which I guess is Ineteger) and then it will be made up of `datacenter`, `client_id`, `data_id`, `data_counter` and they should also be of same data type in Java as shown above in c++.

In Java, I would like to make one final byte array `customer_address` which will be uint64_t and it will made up of `datacenter`, `client_id`, `data_id`, `data_counter` with same data type in Java. How would I do this?

Any simple example will help me to understand better.

**Update**

Does my below method looks right?

```
long client_data(byte datacenter, short client_id, byte data_id, int data_counter) {
    return ((long) (datacenter) << 56) | ((long) client_id << 40) | ((long) data_id << 32) | ((long) data_counter);
}
```

Comment: 64bit int in java is `Long`

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a class?

Comment: @mp_ Actually, I need to send this byte array in network byte order over the network to my c++ program as an input from Java so that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can store the values in a `Long` similar how you do it in C/C++
But pay attention to Javas signed-ness; `+` could give other results than the binary or `|`
Ie. something like that with `Long`´s:

```
customer_address = (datacenter << 56)
                   | (client_id << 40)
                   | (data_id << 32)
                   | data_counter;
```

Of course, you can cast the variables here too, like in C/C++
(if they are not Long already).
A function like in your question could look like that (but with return value
instead of a reference, because that´s a pain in Java for primitive types):

```
long client_data(byte datacenter, 
    short client_id, 
    byte data_id, 
    int data_counter)
{
    return ((long(datacenter) << 56)
    | (long(client_id) << 40)
    | (long(data_id) << 32)
    | long(data_counter));
}
```

Then, you can get a byte array like that:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
b.putLong(blablavariable);
byte[] result = b.array();
```

Converting each part to bytes and concatenating them afterwards
(instead of the `<<`-thing) would work too.

Comment: Thanks deviantfan for suggestion. In this case, how would I declare and what will be the data type for datacenter, client_id, data_id and data_counter?

Comment: See added method above. byte, short, int, long.

Comment: got it now. Thanks for the help. And can you explain me, why did you allocated `8` for Byte Buffer? Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: Because a long has 8 bytes, and therefore the byte array will have 8 elements too.

Comment: I see and by 8 elements you mean to say, 1 byte datacenter, 2 bytes client_id, 1 bytes data_id and 4 bytes data_counter right?

Comment: are you still around? When I tried using `client_data` method in my eclipse, it was giving error on long datatype. Do you know why by any chance? I have updated my question with the method I am using by making some correction. Does that looks right to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63284/discussion-between-user2809564-and-deviantfan).

Comment: are you around? I am in the chat room. Have some basis quick question